# SwiftUI Picker: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time

Tags: xcode, swiftui, llvm

folders are fetched first and they are listed in the second picker(whose selection is $folderSelection), and the selected folder's childlists are shown in the third picker(whose selection is $listSelection.

When I compiled this code, Xcode omits an error(The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time)

By commenting out each block of code, I figured out that the third picker caused the problem, maybe because it is too complicated.

```
Picker("Choose List", selection: $listSelection) {
    ForEach(Array(folderSelection?.childlists?.allObjects)) { index in
        Text(Array(folderSelection!.childlists!.allObjects)[index].name ?? "")
           .tag(Array(folderSelection!.childlists!.allObjects)[index] as ListStruct?)
    }
}
```

I tried to fetch folders and lists by adding init(), but then folderSelection variable becomes problem.

**Update on April 2**

I also tried using .onRecieve for folderSelection Picker, like this

```
Picker("Choose Folder", selection: $folderSelection) {
     ForEach(folders) { (folder: FolderStruct) in
        Text(folder.name ?? ""
            .tag(folder as FolderStruct?)
     }
     .onReceive([self.folderSelection].publisher.first()) { (selectedFolder) in
        lists = selectedFolder?.childlists?.allObjects as! [ListStruct]
     }
}
```

But when I run on Simulator, it omits an error

> Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: force unwrapped a nil value

Is there any solution for this?

**Full code**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct QuizHomeView: View {
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FolderStruct.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var folders: FetchedResults<FolderStruct>
    
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var quizType = "Guess the meaning"
    @State private var folderSelection: FolderStruct?
    @State private var listSelection: ListStruct?
    
    let quizTypes = ["Guess the meaning", "Guess the word"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
           Form {
               Section {
                   Picker("Quiz Type", selection: $quizType) {
                        ForEach(["Guess the meaning", "Guess the word"], id: \.self) {
                            Text(LocalizedStringKey($0))
                        }
                   }
                   .pickerStyle(.segmented)
               }

               Section {
                   Picker("Choose Folder", selection: $folderSelection) {
                       ForEach(folders, id: \.self) { (folder: FolderStruct) in
                           Text(folder.name ?? "")
                               .tag(folder as FolderStruct?)
                       }
                   }
                   
                   Picker("Choose List", selection: $listSelection) {
                       ForEach(Array(folderSelection?.childlists?.allObjects).indices, id: \.self) { index in
                           Text(Array(folderSelection!.childlists!.allObjects).indices[index].name ?? "")
                               .tag(Array(folderSelection!.childlists!.allObjects).indices[index] as ListStruct?)
                       }
                   }
               }
               
               Section {
                   Button("Start") {
                       showSheet.toggle()
                       
                   }
                   .disabled(folderSelection == nil || listSelection == nil)
               }
           }
           .navigationTitle("Quiz")
           .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
               QuizPlayView()
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Entities and Relationships of FolderStruct and ListStruct
[image: FolderStruct]

[image: ListStruct]

Comment: That error usually means an error in your code somewhere. This isn't a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it will be tough for us to help, unless someone happens to just spot it. The best thing to do is comment out code until it builds then uncomment one step at a time until the error is back. Then check in that section. Also, because you are using `ManagedObjects` that conform to identifiable, you should be able to get rid of all of the `id: \.self" in your `ForEach`. Lastly, you should avoid using `.indices` in your `ForEach`

Comment: @Yrb Picker("Choose List", selection: $listSelection) { ForEach(Array(folderSelection?.childlists?.allObjects)) { index in Text(Array(folderSelection!.childlists!.allObjects)[index].name ?? "") .tag(Array(folderSelection!.childlists!.allObjects)[index] as ListStruct?) } } -> this block of code causes the problem

Comment: You need to post `ListStruct`, the `FolderStruct` entity, and any structs or classes they use.

Comment: To get an index (as you expect) from your `Array` in your third `Picker`,
try something like this: `ForEach(Array(folderSelection?.childlists?.allObjects).indices, id: \.self) { index in  ... }`
However, you should restructure your code for the `ForEach` to use the `item` directly without using `index`.

Comment: @Yrb I uploaded them by editing my question.

Comment: You are using too many optionals. The array in `List` must be non-optional. Either declare all properties in Core Data as non-optional or add computed properties in the class to return non-optional values. And three times `folderSelection?.childlists?.allObjects).` is unnecessarily expensive.